# Improve to a generalized question

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, quality-improvement

About a month ago I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29740464) which is specific for `AJAX` and now I would like to make it more generic because oftentimes new users, seeing a specific problem, do not read the entire post <sub>(I was a computer lab assistant at a high school for a few months and the students were behaving in this way)</sub>.

I have no problems to improve my answer, but changing the question I could easily get a rejection <sub>*(I don't have enough reputation to make edits without waiting for approval)*</sub> because I could not respect the original post, so I decided to ask here before of doing anything.

First of all I'm going to ask the owner of the question in his/her post's comments if I can do this thing, but I have some doubts:

- If he/she says **yes** and I change the question, can the reviewers read his/her comment where he/she gives his/her consent?
- Is this a good thing to do? I think that generalizing an already good question will make it better and easier to find, but please tell me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If OP says yes and I change the question, can the reviewers read
> the comment where OP gives consent?

By default, no.  The reviewers get a limited view of the post with only the edit comment and none of the post's comments.  Diligent reviewers will investigate the post on their own without any prompting. You can help reviewers by leaving good edit comments urging them to investigate (like `Generalizing question with OP's approval.  See comments`).  That makes it easier for the less-diligent reviews to understand the rationale behind your (probably rather extensive) edit.

> Is this a good thing to do? I think that generalizing an already good
> question will make it better and easier to find.

Generalizing some questions can be very hard.  I'd personally think it's appropriate in specific situations.  There are many considerations to balance:

- If the question is very easy to generalize, there's a good chance the the question is a *duplicate*.  Edits that improve the question are still fine, but duplicate flagging/closing should probably also take place
- Generalizing the question might invalidate previous answers.  These kinds of edits are frowned upon since they also undermine others' work.  You can (and should) still edit out extraneous information for a *minimal*, verifiable, complete example (an MVCE).
- Over-generalizing can make the question harder to find or understand.  Specific, concrete examples can contain more search terms and be more accessible to specific crowds.  In fact, [a certain degree of duplication is good](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will think well to the pros and cons of improvement and if I feel it's a good move, I'll use your suggestions.